# How do I convert Vue JS templates to pure HTML

Tags: html, angular, vue.js

Good day, I have been asked to convert an entire VueJs template into pure HTML to use it in Angular.

I have access to all of Vue's files, in fact the entire code base, but is there a 'quick' way to convert these templates to regular HTML?

Answer (score 2):

There's no tool for it. Here are the basics:

- `:attribute="x"` or `v-bind:attribute="x"` =>

  - `[attribute]="x"` for custom attributes
  - `[attr.attribute]="x"` for native HTML attributes
  - `[(attribute)]="x"` for two-way binding (inputs)
- `@event="x"` or `v-on:event="x"` => `(event)="x"`
- `v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key"` => `*ngFor="let item of items;let key=index;"`
- `v-if="x"` => `*ngIf="x"`
- `v-else` reference moves on the `*ngIf` element: `*ngIf="x; else other"` and somewhere in your component you define `<ng-template #other>...other content here</ng-template>`

If you run into edge cases, ask, and I'll update the answer.
You might find [this](https://www.codegram.com/blog/from-vue-to-angular/) useful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the guide and support, I'll try to use the guide and the examples you gave me to try to do it.